# Force Azure Data Factory to refresh branch from remote Git

Tags: git, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory (ADF) with Git integrated. In some cases I need to force ADF to refresh my branch status, but I am unable. EDIT: I am on my feature branch, not in the live mode.

To reproduce:

1. I have a branch (my-branch) pushed to the remote
2. In ADF I select my-branch. I make some changes and I save it. In the background the ADF commits and pushes the changes to the remote
3. Locally I fetch, and I switch to the branch, I do some other changes in my-branch and I push it
4. I cannot find a way how to force ADF to understand that my-branch has newer version on remote. When I make other changes, ADF continues where it has left my-branch and force pushes its changes. Meaning that it overwrites my changes on the remote.

I am trying to refresh page, change to other branch and back, but it doesn't help.

As a workaround:

1. I create another branch (my-branch-adf1..) for each planned ADF change, push it
2. Refresh ADF to load it to the list of available branches
3. Save ADF changes
4. I cherry pick changes made by ADF to my-branch

There has to be a way how to reset ADF to the remote state, hasn't it?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot find a way how to force ADF to understand that my-branch has
> newer version on remote.

Use Overwrite live mode functionality

[image]

It publishes or overwrites the code from your collaboration branch into the live mode. It will consider the code in your repository as the source of truth.

Refer this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#troubleshooting-git-integration) for more information

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This option only works when in a _Collaboration branch_. My case is about working on my feature branch and debugging it without going to live mode yet.